# Dissapearing clear button during .WhileEditing

Tags: ios, swift

I subclass `UITextField` and add a green button that I want to display
when I edit or touch the textfield, as shown below:

```
class TextField: UITextField {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.textAlignment = .Center
        self.textColor = .whiteColor()
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(7.0)
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
        self.borderStyle = .RoundedRect

        var frame = clearButtonRectForBounds(bounds)
        frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        let button = UIButton(type: .System)
        button.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.rightView = button
        self.rightView?.contentMode = .Center
        self.rightViewMode = .WhileEditing
    }

}
```

I then initiate an instance of it in `ViewController` below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var textField: TextField! {
        didSet {
            textField.delegate = self
            textField.placeholder = "I'm a text field"
            superview.addSubview(textField)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField = TextField()
        textField.text = "I'm some text"
    }

}
```

When I click on the textfield for the **first time** the green button shows up. If I
resign the keyboard (by pressing enter) then click on the textfield again, the green button doesn't show up
until I delete a character.

**QUESTION 1** How can I get the green button to show up everytime i click the textfield?

If I keep selecting the textfield and pressing enter I eventually get the warning:

```
`Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.`
```

**QUESTION 2** Why do I get this warning?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help (question 1)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401263/uitextfield-rightviewmode-odd-behaviour

Comment: @Emptyless this helped me find the problem by printing the button's frame in, which was being shifted off due to AutoLayout... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Changing:

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

to:

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

fixed **QUESTION 1**.